# Using awk command and comparing with a command output in another machine

Tags: unix, awk

I am looking to check if a random UID on one machine is present on another machine and printing if it exists. I am pretty new to awk and have hit a roadblock.Here is how I am approaching the problem:
Pick a random line in /etc/passwd, get the 3rd column which is the UID; ssh to another machine , get the /etc/passwd contents ,check if the reference UID from the first machine is present in the 3rd column of any line and print it.
I am only able to reach up until the point where I get the reference UID. How do I use this value, ssh into another machine and compare if it exists:

```
    shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | awk '{print $3}' <the reference UID> <ssh 10.0.0.0> cat /etc/passwd <compare if reference UID is present>
```

Comment: `xargs` can help you by calling ssh and puting the UID in the right place

Comment: Thanks @Oerd. I used xargs and edited the command as below. But how can I pass the output of up until the second pipe to the awk command on the second machine ?  `shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{print $3}' | xargs ssh 10.0.0.1 cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '$3==<output till second pipe> {print $0}'`

Comment: I'm not an `xargs`master, so there might be a better way, but you can write everything in a shell script that is invoked by xargs. in the script you can put parameters where you see fit :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing that:

```
awk -vuid=$(shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $3}') -F: '$3 == uid' <( ssh host cat /etc/passwd)
```

Breaking it down:

1. This part stores uid : `-vuid=$(shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $3}')`
2. This will print the line if 3rd field matches our uid: `'$3 == uid'`
3. here we're treating output of ssh command as a file: `<( ssh host cat /etc/passwd)`